# Related to preprocessing data in sklearn using python

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#mydataset = pd.read_csv('AttributeDataset.csv')
names =
['Dress_ID','Style','Price','Rating','Size','Season','NeckLine', 
'SleeveLength','waiseline','Material','FabricType','Decoration','Pattern 
Type','Recommendaation']
dataframe = pd.read_csv('AttributeDataset.csv',names=names)
print(dataframe.shape)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,:-1]
Y = array[:,-1]

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(X_train)`
```

For this code, we are unable to fit the data. When we compile this code the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-3df12e017cba>", line 1, in <module>
    le.fit(X)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing    \label.py", line 95, in fit
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 614, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (501, 13).
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue? And explain to us how to preprocess the data and convert it from categorical to numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass an array to LabelEncoder object's fit method but you are passing a matrix to it (X_train). Find the columns which has categorical values in X_train and pass it to the LabelEncoder like,

```
le = le.fit(X_train[:, 0]) // to encode the first column
X_train[:, 0] = le.transform(X_train[:, 0]) // to convert to numerical
```

You can do both fit and transform in the same call using,

```
X_train[:, 0] = le.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
```

Comment: @dornalaswethareddy accept this as answer if it works